# Not able to delete node attribute using knife command

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, cookbook

I have created cookbook for enabling some of the windows feature and rebooting the machine using [WindowsRebootHandler](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_windows.html). As shown in below code, I have used ruby_block to not perform the same action in the subsequent runs.

```
windows_batch 'Enable_MS_Feature' do
  code <<-EOH
    #My script
  EOH
  notifies :create, "ruby_block[WindowsFeature_Install]", :immediately
  notifies :request, 'windows_reboot[60]'
  not_if { node.attribute?("WindowsFeature_Installed") }
end

ruby_block "WindowsFeature_Install" do
  block do
    node.set['WindowsFeature_Installed'] = true
    node.save
  end
  action :nothing
end
```

For testing purpose, I have to delete `WindowsFeature_Installed` attribute to perform the action again. So, I have used below command.

```
knife exec -E "nodes.transform(:all) {|n| n.delete('WindowsFeature_Installed');n.save() }"
```

Above command is not deleting the node attribute. When I searched for the same attribute using knife command, it listed all the nodes.

```
knife search node "WindowsFeature_Installed:true"
```

To debug further, have enabled verbose output of the commands and all the HTTP responses from chef-server were OK.

Also, tried to check chef-server logs for error details. But was not able to identify the issue as many process logs are present related to chef-server package.

So, how can I remove this attribute to perform the recipe action again? Or in which chef-server log, node attribute delete details will be logged? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Try `n.set['WindowsFeature_Installed']=nil` instead of `n.delete('WindowsFeature_Installed')`.

Comment: @Draco Thanks for the reply. I have already tried `n.set` and was able to perform the recipe action again. `knife exec -E "nodes.transform(:all) {|n| n.set['WindowsFeature_Installed']=false;n.save }"`. But, I am wondering why `n.delete` is failing.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I could not delete a attribute from the node but modifying via **set** worked. What help me to solve this was to look on which level the attribute was generated by one of my recipes.

For example to delete attribute "network_interfaces" look at your current notes config.

```
knife node show -l -F json <node_name>
```

You should get a similar output from your nodes-config:

```
{
  "name": "<node_name>",
  "chef_environment": "_default",
  "run_list": [
   ...
  ],
  "normal": {
     "tags": [
     ],
    "network_interfaces": {
       "order": [
         "vpn_vpn"
       ]
    },
  },
  "default": {
     ...
  },
  ...
```

In my case I wanted to delete the **network_interfaces**-attribute from all nodes. So I executed:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform(:all) { |n| n.normal_attrs.delete("network_interfaces"); n.save() }'
```

instead of:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform(:all) { |n| n.delete("network_interfaces"); n.save() }'
```

More about the different attribute precedence levels can be found here: https://coderwall.com/p/rfm4lg

A great article about querying for node attributes with knife: http://www.programmersparadox.com/2013/02/05/viewing-chef-node-attributes-with-knife/